# How to bundle Webkit into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, webkit, swt, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) now allows using Webkit as an underlying renderer for the SWT browser component. Nevertheless, [runtime requirements](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit) say that Safari must be installed on the target machine. Is there a way to avoid this requirement by bundling Webkit/Safari into Eclipse similarly to how XULRunner is bundled?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution how to use webkit with eclipse?

Comment: @Fedor, no I haven't found a way of bundling Webkit into Eclipse.

Comment: If you find a solution - please post it.  I too am interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Genuitec](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html) did something that could help you.
from Genuite:

> WebKit for SWT is an open-source embeddable Java(tm) WebKit browser
>   component developed by Genuitec and contributed to the Eclipse Blinki
>   Mobile DevKit project. WebKit for SWT can be used in the development
>   of a wide range of Java SWT standalone and RCP applications that
>   require integration of rich internet content, and services.

Comment: Yes, they did but only for Windows platform. Anyway, this project seems to be dead.